# Why does this USB-C connection only work in one connector orientation?

Tags: usb, connector, usb-c, pinout

I have a setup of devices connected as follows:

```
        A    B   C
[laptop]<---<<--->[keyboard]
```

Where

- `<-` is a male USB-C connector,
- `>-` is a female USB-C connector,
- `[laptop]` is a [Dell 5470](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ca/product-support/product/precision-14-5470-laptop/docs), and
- `[keyboard]` is a [Keychron K3Pro](https://www.keychron.com/products/keychron-k3-pro-qmk-via-wireless-custom-mechanical-keyboard).

Only one orientation of the connectors at position `B` results in communication between the laptop and keyboard.  I expected the results to be the same regardless of orientation because I thought the USB-C design resulted in rotational symmetry for all connections.

I connected the same cable assembly to a [cable tester](https://caberqu.com/home/20-c2c-caberqu-746052578813.html) as shown in the following photographs:

[image]
[image]

The different connection orientations have the results shown in the following table:

| A | B | C | Communication | CC1 | CC2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0° | 0° | 0° | yes | On | Dim |
| 0° | 0° | 180° | yes | On | Dim |
| 0° | 180° | 180° | no | Dim | On |
| 0° | 180° | 0° | no | Dim | On |

The LEDs on the tester were lit for each of the test cases as follows:

- `Pinrow B D-`, `Pinrow B D-`: Off
- `CC1`,`CC2`: per table
- All others: On

Testers connected to the M to M cable to show the following:

[image]
[image]

I don't have a way of connecting the M to F cable directly to a wiring tester.  The M to F tester does not seem to have an eMarker.

[USB Device Tree Viewer](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html)
shows the following when successfully connected with this cable assembly:

[image]

I have read that [USB-C extension cables are not in accordance with the specification](https://www.reddit.com/r/UsbCHardware/comments/10xj74r/why_dont_usbc_extension_cables_work/j7svggo).  Indeed one such cable is in this assembly.  However, I would still like to understand the mechanism that causes one connector orientation to work and the other not.  Since this connection is between a laptop and keyboard, I don't think the general concerns over current capacity and eMarkers apply in this case or explain the phenomenon.

I've also read through [this post about the CC pin and connector orientation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/482150/type-a-usb-3-0-with-type-c-usb-3-0-orientation).  I don't have a breakout board to measure the whether there is a pullup on the CC pin in either of the cables.  For that matter, I don't know whether such a pullup would be relevant here.

1. What part of this assembly isn't rotationally symmetric?
2. Why does the the brightness of the `CC1` and `CC2` LEDs swap when the connector orientation is reversed?
3. In principle, are there other standard-compliant or commonly-encountered configurations where a successful connection depends on the orientation of a USB-C connector?

Comment: halfway down https://hackaday.com/2022/12/27/all-about-usb-c-illegal-adapters/#more-564492

Comment: Did the tester show the cable with plugs on both ends are OK? Also it would help to know if the standard cable with plugs is of which type, likely full-featured but is it an active cable containing an e-marker or purely passive cable? It would also help to know if keyboard uses USB3 for some reason like to assume more power is available than on USB2.

Comment: @dandavis that DE-9 "USB" receptacle made my teeth hurt.

Comment: It's a touch pedantic I'll admit but technically correct.  B is the 25-pin shell size.

Comment: @Justme I added the test results for the patch cable including the eMarker readout as well as the readout from USB Device Tree Viewer.

Comment: As I understand it, the two CC pins in USB-C are used for different purposes. Either will work for either purpose, so everything should operate fine regardless of cable orientation. But if one of them is damaged/weak/corroded, the symptoms will differ depending on which way the cable is oriented, and it may work one way but not the other.

Answer (score 3):

1. While the plug is symmetric and it can be plugged in in any orientation, it does not mean the connections are symmetric in any way. In fact they are asymmetric. The host and device need to detect all the four combinations how a cable can be connected between them and switch the data pins correctly so they run in the cable as per the specification, if only 2 lanes out of 4 are used, or 4 out of 4. Which is only relevant for an USB3 device of course, and USB2 only case is simpler, as long as CC pins are allowed to do their job properly. And if the CC pins do not do their job properly, the PC cannot  detect that anything is plugged in so it would not even try to send power to the port or communicate through it. If CC pins work incorrectly, PC might detect that something is plugged in and power it, but if cable flip detection is bypassed, it will not be able to communicate over USB3 wires if they are incorrectly flipped, so the device may determine it has been connected to USB2 only port and determine it can't draw USB3 amount of current.
2. That's because swapping the connector orientation swaps CC1 and CC2 and all other data pins too. Only power/ground pins are symmetric. Even the USB2 data pins run on one set of pins on the plug, not both. The cables with plugs are not straight through, they should be thought more like Ethernet crossover or serial null-modem cables. CC1 and CC2 are only two separate names for two wires, their function being CC and VCONN depends on which way you insert the plug, and only one of them looks like is working properly according to the tester. This tells the problem is in the cables, so it's the extender cable or the regular cable and if it's an active cable it could explain the difference. CC pins are especially important, because they are used to detect if something is plugged in or not, which way that something is plugged in, and the initial roles of the plugged in devices.
3. No, there should not be. Every standard compliant device must work with other standard compliant devices and cables. The problem is, many cheap devices that have a Type-C connector may be designed in a way that is incompliant, because it's cheaper for an USB3 device. For USB2 device, it may simply be an accidental Type-C design error never caught until thousands of devices are already made, because they did work with compliant Type-A to Type-C adapter cable. And for the Type-C extender cables, as they are not defined in the standard as allowed, there is no standard or allowed way to wire them, so in practice, how they should be wired if they were being made is guesswork and different extenders may be wired differently so you don't really know what you get when when buying a Type-C extender cable. You don't even know if the receptacle on the extender should be on PC or keyboard side, if it has been made directional for some reason.

The Type-C extender cables are useless anyway, as you can just buy long enough cables to begin with, and if there are no cables with the length you need, then it means that USB specs or cable parameters are limiting the length for proper data transmission, and the signal may degrade too much with the extender to work properly.

Type-C extender cables are also dangerous as there are no specs how these should be made, as they should not even be made, as they allow you to pass 20V 5A through an extension cable intended for 5V 3A. So as these are not compliant cables that USB members are not allowed to manufacture as per the licensing agreements, only non-USB members will manufacture these in any way they find them suitable, which means they do not have to work in any way with any compliant USB cable.

Comment: _”The Type-C extender cables are useless anyway, as you can just buy long enough cables to begin with…”_.   Hmm…how then does one forward a device port to an instrument panel.  That’s a cabling function that certainly is useful.  Equipment rack installations, for example, seem to commonly forward connections to patch panels for all but the most exotic connections (including USB Type-A.)

Comment: @alx9r Well, not with USB Type-C, as it's not intended for that, officially. Now that does not prevent such adapters or cables of varying quality being available. It also depends what you intend to pass over Type-C, 100W of power, USB 2 data, USB 3 data, DisplayPort, or all four, or same things in the form of ThunderBolt, or Type-C passive headphone adapter.

Comment: _"...if the CC pins do not do their job properly, the PC cannot detect that anything is plugged in so it would not even try to send power to the port or communicate through it."_  I think then, my leading hypothesis is that this extension cable only forwards one of the two CC pins, which would be completely consistent with that deciding on the pinout for such a cable is guesswork.  I would have to obtain the right breakout connections to confirm this directly.

Comment: For that matter, I suppose the extension cable might only forward one of each the two D+, D-, and CC pins.